# Как указать свою группу настроек?

Tags: php, kohana

Народ, как указать свою группу настроек (не default). Kohana 3.2.

Вот как выглядит кусок кода с пагинацией

```
$count = ORM::factory('product')->count_all();
        $pagination = Pagination::factory(array(
                'total_items' => $count,
        ));

        //Вывод из БД записей
        $products = ORM::factory('product')

                ->limit($pagination->items_per_page)
                ->order_by('id', 'desc')
                ->offset($pagination->offset)
                ->find_all();
```

Вот как выглядит файл конфига

```
return array(

    // Application defaults
    'default' => array(
        'current_page'      => array('source' => 'route', 'key' => 'page'), // source: "query_string" or "route"
        'total_items'       => 0,
        'items_per_page'    => 10,
        'view'              => 'pagination/floating',
        'auto_hide'         => TRUE,
        'first_page_in_url' => FALSE,
        'uri_segment'       => 'page'
    ),

        'admin' => array(
        'current_page'      => array('source' => 'route', 'key' => 'page'), // source: "query_string" or "route"
        'total_items'       => 0,
        'items_per_page'    => 50,
        'view'              => 'pagination/floating',
        'auto_hide'         => TRUE,
        'first_page_in_url' => FALSE,
        'uri_segment'       => 'page'
    ),

);
```

Comment: Группа настроек для чего? Для какова компонента?

Comment: Для пагинации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен - пишу по тому что увидел в коде модуля, но должно быть как-то так:

```
$pagination = Pagination::factory(array(
    'total_items' => $count,
));
$pagination->setup(array('group' => 'default'));
```

А вместо 'default' поставте свой ключ с конфигов.

Comment: Спасибо огромное) Пробовал Pagination::setup('group' =>'admin') - без результата) Я был близок)))